# Is there a way to run access with vba code correctly on mac?

Tags: vba, macos, ms-access, bootcamp

I am trying to run MS Access application that includes VBA code on a mac device but unfortunately, there's no access version for mac os. So I ran windows 10 on it using bootcamp and installed ms access 2019 and the access application run correctly except that VBA code cannot run at all it!
It generates an error that "the database cannot be opened because the VBA project contained in it cannot be read"

So is there a way to run MS Access applications with VBA code correctly on mac device?

any help will be appreciated.

Comment: There's no difference between Windows on bootcamp and Windows on a normal PC. However, setup issues are not on-topic here. Try [su] and make sure to provide more info

Comment: This might be the result of having installed Office x64 as opposed to office x32 (x86) version. This case is especially if you are attempting to run a accDE (compiled access application). Quite recent, office started installing the x64 bit version as opposed for the last 20+ years installing the x32 bit version by default. So running office on windows is what you have and are doing. So, your question is not effected due to you running parrells here, but is a 100% windows problem and question.  Any program that works on windows will work on parralles 100% the same.

Comment: Thanks I appreciate your comments.that's true I found the reason of that problem. It was related to the windows  and updating windows soved the problem